# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0:sval:' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0:sval:' to data type int.

Please help, I'm getting this error message when looking for data for specific dates in my table.

My query:

```
SELECT *,
CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) as XTRA_REPORTED_DATE
FROM [RS].[REPORTS].[V_VALIDATOR_DIAGNOSTIC_EVENT_EXPLODED]
WHERE TXN_DATE_TIME BETWEEN '2021-09-28 22:13:36' AND '2021-09-28 22:13:37'
AND IS_OK=0
```

The function the table is using:

```
FUNCTION [REPORTS].[godValidatorSplit] (@inputString varchar(max), @isInputHex tinyint)
RETURNS @return TABLE (val varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml xml
    SET @xml = CONVERT(xml,'<v>'+
    REPLACE(REPLACE(@inputString,',','</v><v>'),char(10),'')
    +'</v>')
    
    INSERT INTO @return(val)
    SELECT  CASE    
                WHEN (@isInputHex<>0) 
                THEN
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (v.value('.','varchar(MAX)') NOT LIKE '%[^a-fA-F0-9]%')
                        THEN convert(bigint, convert(varbinary, '0x' + RIGHT('00000000'+v.value('.','varchar(MAX)'),8), 1))
                        ELSE 0
                    END
                ELSE v.value('.','varchar(MAX)')
            END
    FROM @xml.nodes('/v') as a(v)

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Indeed, `'0:sval:'` is not a valid `int`.

Comment: Defunetly your input format is not what your proc expects. One of them should be corrected.

Comment: Well, the query is working in general, but I'm getting this error in some specific point of time, for ex, If I change the time in the query above only few seconds, I will get a result.

Comment: FYI, if you are using user defined table value functions you should really being using inline TVFs. Multi-line TVFs are notoriously slow. Also, what does the function have to do with the first statement? It's not used on it. I feel like we're missing something here. Take the time to post a full [mre].